# MatSelect is not firing change event in case of preselection

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material-6

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="25" class="pr-12" *ngFor="let htmlMarketLevel of marketLevels">
    <mat-label>{{htmlMarketLevel.MarketLevelName}}</mat-label>
    <mat-select name="Market{{htmlMarketLevel.Rank}}" [(ngModel)]="selectedMarket[htmlMarketLevel.Rank]" [compareWith]="compareMarkets" (selectionChange)="populateChildrenMarkets( $event )">
        <mat-option>All</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let market of markets[htmlMarketLevel.Rank]" [value]="market">{{market.MarketName}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I have multiple select fields that are generated dynamically. Now I have an issue, if my select field is populated and an option is selected it's not firing the selectionChange event. But if it's a user action then it's firing the event.